# How to prove that a deep network perform better than random classifier?

Tags: classification, deep-learning

I'm using a deep network for a two class problem and I'm using F1 score as a metric. How to prove that my classification result is better than random classifier? I usually do randomization test for, for instance, 1000 time and then I fit the random classification results with the best distribution, then I perform the right-tailed test. However, this is not feasible in case of deep networks. For a matric like F1 it's hard to tell what the level of chance based on the classes labels ratio. Also, I'm not sure how to use AUC-ROC in case of deep network. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have a binary classifier and the performance of your deep neural network classifier can be measured/expressed using the ROC curve. You want your classifier to be performing such as the ROC curve is following as much as possible to the left and above the diagonal. If the curve is very close to the diagonal, the classifier is random. If the curve is below the diagonal, your classifier is worse than random; (probably the training labels and test labels are inverted).